# Intuition for why the Invariance Propereties of the Haar measure is Useful for Generating Random Unitaties for Quantum Scrambling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I understand that the Haar measure $\mu_{H}$ allows us to generate random unitaries to act on states in order to randomize them.

From my understanding, the Haar measure is a uniform probability measure with the invariance properety that for $M,V\in U(N)$ and a probability density function $f$, we have 
$$\mathbb{P}(X)=\int_{X}f(V)~d\mu_{H}=\int_X f(VM)~d\mu_{H}=\int_{X} f(MV)~d\mu_{H}$$

for $X\subset U(n)$.

I've been told that this invariance property is a very useful property for generating random unitarities. Why is that the case though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a unitary is chosen at random, you want every unitary to be "equally likely". So in particular if you have a subset $\mathcal X\subset \mathrm{U}(1)$ and you multiply it with another unitary $U$, then $U\mathcal X$ is just "the same set" of unitaries, just "displaced" within the unitary group.  It should therefore have the same probability, $\mu(U\mathcal X)=\mu(\mathcal X)$, which is exactly what the Haar measure demands.

(In analogy, if you want a random distribution on the unit circle $[0;2\pi)$, then any interval $I$ of the same length should have the same probability, i.e., $I$ and $\phi+I$ should have the same probability measure.)